# AS3 ByteArray readShort

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

i have to read a sequence of bytes,that was written in different ways (writeBite, writeShort and writeMultiByte) and display them has list of HEX byte on video.
My problem is convert the number 1500, i tryed other number and the results was correct...
here is a an example:

```
var bytes:Array = [];
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeShort(1500);

ba.position = 0;

for (var i=0; i<ba.length; i++)
{
   bytes.push(ba.readByte().toString(16));
}
trace(bytes);//5,-24 i'm expetting 5,DC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `readByte` reads a signed byte (ranges from -128 to 127). The most significant bit defines the sign. In case of numbers greater than `127` (like `DC`) that bit will be `1` and the number will be seen as a negative number. The [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) of the *negative* byte is used to get the signed value. In case of `DC`, which is `1101 1100` in binary the complement would be `0010 0011` which is `23`. A one is added and the value will be regarded as negative, which will give you the `-24` you are seeing.

You should use [readUnsignedByte](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#readUnsignedByte%28%29) to read values from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no real Byte type in AS3, `readByte()` returns an int. You can try this instead:

```
for (var i=0; i<ba.length; i++)
{
    bytes.push(ba[i].toString(16));
}
```